# C++ CString format with %f, double number became very big value

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings

I am maintaining C++ project but i am not family with C++.

I am facing an issue, we use `CString` to convert a `double` value to String by

```
double Dose;
CString Dose2;
if(Dose>0)
{
    Dose2.Format("%f",Dose);
}else{
    Dose2.Format("0");
}
```

When I set break point after format `%f` line of code, the value before and after totally different.

Can you explain why this problem occurred? Some time the string value is correct, sometime not correct.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced there's enough code to allow a confident diagnosis.  However, the value in `Dose` in the code shown is indeterminate, I believe.  If it was determinate, the value would almost certainly be zero, in which case you'd not get into the format code with `%f`.

Comment: some time the value for Dose2 return 0.000000 too, some time it show big number, is this leak issue?

Comment: In the first code snippet in your question, `Dose` is not properly initialized (for example `double Dose = 123.5;`), so the value can be anything.

Comment: I can't tell because there isn't enough code.  I'm also not familiar with MFC.  However, the code shown does not ensure there is a known value in `Dose`, which means you get whatever you get.  If there's other code not shown that ensures `Dose` has a sane value, you should show it — or a sufficiently good approximation to the code.  Read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write `Dose` value to file before format string, it also had big value.

```
FILE *fpversion;
fpversion = fopen("doserate.txt", "a");
fprintf(fpversion, "%f", Dose);
fclose(fpversion);
```

I take a look at source code set `Dose` value in another dialog.

```
if(m_MapDlg.GetSafeHwnd()!=NULL)
{
    m_MapDlg.Dose=Result;
}
```

I tried to make function to set `Dose` value as

```
void CMapDlg::SetDose(double dose) {
    this->Dose = dose;
}
```

And replace

```
m_MapDlg.Dose=Result;
```

by

```
m_MapDlg.SetDose(Result);
```

The `Dose` value got corrected value.

I shared my solution for whom concerned.

Thank @Jonathan Leffler for your suggestion.

Comment: This probably works only by accident. kotatsuyaki already pointed out the likely cause (uninitialized variable). Changing your code a bit can hide the Undefined Behavior, changing your code further may very well cause new symptoms. You will need to find someone who is familiar with C++ to fix the real bug.

Comment: I also tried to init Dose = 0 as kotatsuyaki's suggestion but it still not work.